# Filtering data-frame on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which has a head that looks like:

```
               Shop       Opening date  
0            London                NaT  
22         Brighton         01/03/2016  
27       Manchester         01/31/2017  
54          Bristol         03/31/2017  
69          Glasgow         04/09/2017
```

I also have a variable `startPeriod` which is set to 1/04/2017 date and `endPeriod` variable that has a value of 30/06/17

I am trying to create a new dataframe based on `df` that filters out any rows that do not have a date (so removing any rows with an `Opening date` of NaT) and also filter out any rows with an opening date between the startPeriod and endPeriod.  So in the above example I would be left with the following new dataframe:

```
                 Shop       Opening date  
22           Brighton         01/03/2016  
69            Glasgow         04/09/2017
```

I have tried to filter out the 'NaT' using the following:

```
df1 = df['Opening date '] != 'NaT'
```

but am unsure how to also filter out any Opening date that are inside the `startPeriod`/`endPeriod` range.

Comment: Use `pd.Series.between`. Also, use `pd.Series.isnull` instead of string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df[df['date'].between('2016-03-01', '2017-04-05')]
print (df)
   Shop     Opening       date
2    27  Manchester 2017-01-31
3    54     Bristol 2017-03-31
```

I think filtering out `NaN`s is not necessary, but if need it chain new condition:

```
df = df[df['date'].between('2016-03-01', '2017-04-05') & df['date'].notnull()]
```

Comment: Many thanks @jezerael.  Using .between returns rows with dates between these dates if I want the dates that are not between the dates do you know how I could do it? Would I use a ~ ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. `df[~df['date'].between('2016-03-01', '2017-04-05')]`, `~` is for invert boolean mask.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried every combination of date format and am using ~ but I still get returned rows that are between the dates not outside, any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: I have no idea, it should works. There is same output if `~` and if omited?

Comment: Figured it out, needed to change the type of the data-frame date column to date-time and also format the dates yyyy-mm-dd.  Thanks

Comment: Then need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`, I think parameter format is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be careful with the space after date in `df['Opening date ']`

try this solution:

```
df1 = df[df['Opening date'] != 'NaT']
```

it would be much better if you create a copy of the subset you're making

```
df1 = df[df['Opening date'] != 'NaT'].copy()
```